# Propagator, mass and electrostatic potential of an modified 2+1 dimensional Maxwell action

Tags: electromagnetism, quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, maxwell-equations, chern-simons-theory

Consider the modified Maxwell action in 2 + 1 dimensions
$$S=\int d^3x[-\frac{1}{4} F^{\mu\nu} F_{\mu\nu}+\frac{\theta}{2}\epsilon^{\alpha\mu\nu}A_\alpha F_{\mu\nu}]  .$$

The action invariant under gauge transformation, I want to find the propagator and the mass term of the gauge field and then understand what is the electrostatic potential between two charged particles coupled to $A_\mu$ at large distances.

I think the mass term is $\theta$ only by dimensional analysis but I'm still confused for the fact that the last term look like $\frac{\theta}{2}A_\alpha\partial_\mu A_\nu$ with the anti simmetrisazion come from Levi-Civita symbol and not very like $\frac{m^2}{2}A_\mu A^\mu.$

I remember that for the Maxwell term in 3+1 dimensions the action is $S=\int d^4x[-\frac{1}{4} F^{\mu\nu} F_{\mu\nu}]$ and after integration by parts and using Fourier transform we find that the propagator via the quadratic form $\eta^{\mu\nu}q^2-q^\mu q^\nu$' and imposing Lorenz gauge condition: $q^\nu A_\nu=0$  so the final propagator would be:
$\Delta_{\mu\nu}=\frac{\eta_{\mu\nu}}{q^2}$. but in this case i'm not quiet sure if the propagator is the same or I need to do some manipulation with the second term in the action to get some "modified propagator"

After I'll get the propagator to find the electrostatic potential would be automatic.

Comment: the modified action is gauge invariant only if $\theta$ is an integer. This extra term is the famous "Chern-Simons" interaction which is quite ubiquitous in cond-mat.

Comment: https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/proving-modified-maxwell-action-is-gauge-invariant.1003094/ no one said here that there is limitation on $\theta$ values.

Comment: no one there is familiar with Maxwell-Chern-Simons theories? It is a very standard subject, a simple google search should give you plenty of results...

Answer (score 1):

I am recently learning Chern-Simons theory. The E.O.M is
$$\partial_\mu F^{\mu\nu}+
\frac{\theta}{2}\epsilon^{\nu\rho\sigma}F_{\rho\sigma}=0.$$
As we are working in 3d, there are only 3 $F$'s. So it is easier to work with $F$ rather than $A$. Define
$$F^{\nu}=\frac{1}{2}\epsilon^{\nu\rho\sigma}F_{\rho\sigma},$$
or explicitly
$$F^2=F_{01},\quad F^1=-F_{02},\quad F^0=F_{12}.$$
Then the E.O.M looks like (If I did the computation correctly)
$$\begin{align}
\partial_1 F^2 - \partial_2 F^1 + \theta F^0 &= 0 \tag{1}\\
\partial_0 F^2 + \partial_2 F^0 - \theta F^1 &= 0 \tag{2}\\
\partial_0 F^1 + \partial_1 F^0 + \theta F^2 &= 0. \tag{3}\\
\end{align}$$
Then do some organization. By $-\partial_1(1)+\partial_0(2)+(3)$, we get
$$\partial_0^2 F^2-\partial_1^2 F^2+\partial_2(\partial_0F^0+\partial_1F^1)+\theta^2F^2=0.$$
Finally, notice that $\partial_0F^0+\partial_1F^1=-\partial_2F^2$, we arrived at a wave equation with mass $\theta$
$$\partial_0^2 F^2 - \partial_1^2 F^2 - \partial_2^2 F^2 + \theta^2F^2=0.$$
You can also using vector calculus to simplify the EOM. Suppose that we have done a Wick rotation so that there will not be $-1$ around the $t$ index bothering us, the EOM reads
$$\vec{\nabla}\times \vec{F}-\theta \vec{F}=0$$
Then
$$\vec{\nabla}\times\vec{\nabla}\times \vec{F}-\theta \vec{\nabla}\times\vec{F}=
\nabla(\vec{\nabla}\cdot\vec{F})-\nabla^2\vec{F}-\theta^2\vec{F}=0.$$
Then by $\vec{\nabla}\cdot\vec{F}=0$, you can get the same wave equation.

The $\theta$ here need not be an integer classically. However, when you quantize it, it has to be in $\mathbb{Z}$ (I saw only examples in non-Abelian case).